# Using DateValue in a Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to change a column of text-based dates in a table into valued dates, so I can later filter them in the next line of code.  I wanted the code to go through each row, get the value from the Due Date column, and return the date in the correct format.  I get a Run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
    'changes the date to correct format
    For Each Row In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ISP_Table")
    DueDate = Range("ISP_Table[Due Date]")
    Range("ISP_Table[Due Date]") = DateValue(DueDate)
    Next Row
    
    'filters out dates more than 3 months in the future
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ISP_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<" & DateAdd("m", 1, Date)
```

Comment: It will be really helpful to show the data

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the cells in the `.DataBodyRange` of the `ListColumn` in question:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ISP_Table").ListColumns("Due Date").DataBodyRange
    cell.Value = DateValue(cell.Value)
Next
```

Since looping cell-by-cell is slow, even better, use an array:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ISP_Table").ListColumns("Due Date").DataBodyRange

Dim arr() As Variant
arr = rng.Value  ' read values into array

Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(arr, 1) to Ubound(arr, 1)
   arr(i, 1) = DateValue(arr(i, 1))
Next

rng.Value = arr ' write array back to sheet
```